Spring boot with 2 DataSources
I am trying to set up a spring boot application using 2 datasources.
I found this repo:
https://github.com/kota65535/spring-data-jdbc-multi-repos/tree/master
It is exactly what I need, 2 DS, no JPA. I cloned it and it works.
I set up my project with exactly the same configuration. And it was not working, when I start I get the error :
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext' available: expected single matching bean but found 2

There is 2 JdbcMappingContext, 2 datasource, 2 transactionManager etc..
The only difference is that I am using Spring boot 3.3.4 vs 3.1.5 in the example.
I switch my project to 3.1.5 and no more error it works fine.
How I can use 2 datasources with an up to date Spring (maybe a change in Spring 6.0 vs 6.1) ?
Thanks

Spring Boot 3.1.6 is the latest version where tests are passing.

I opened a PR with the changes from my answer: https://github.com/kota65535/spring-data-jdbc-multi-repos/pull/7

TL;DR
I made https://github.com/kota65535/spring-data-jdbc-multi-repos work with Spring Boot 3.4.1. Pull request here.
All beans in Db1Config.java had to be annotated as primary. I also had to bump versions for a couple of dependencies.
I updated the test just to make sure both data sources are still in use (see below).
settings.gradle: Bumped versions
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone"
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id "org.springframework.boot" version springBootVersion
        id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.11"
        id "com.avast.gradle.docker-compose" version "0.17.12"
    }
}

rootProject.name = "spring-data-jdbc-test"

Db1Config.java: Made all beans primary
package com.kota65535.config;


import com.kota65535.config.Db1Config.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBeanDb1;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DataAccessStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcConverter;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.RelationResolver;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.EnableJdbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.relational.RelationalManagedTypes;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.NamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@EnableJdbcRepositories(
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = JdbcRepositoryFactoryBeanDb1.class,
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerDb1",
    basePackages = {
        "com.kota65535.repository.one"
    }
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class}
)
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Db1Config {

  private final AbstractJdbcConfiguration base;

  public Db1Config(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.base = new AbstractJdbcConfiguration();
    this.base.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasources.one")
  public HikariDataSource dataSourceDb1() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public NamedParameterJdbcOperations jdbcOperationsDb1(
      @Qualifier("db1") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerDb1(
      @Qualifier("db1") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public RelationalManagedTypes jdbcManagedTypesDb1() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return base.jdbcManagedTypes();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public JdbcMappingContext jdbcMappingContextDb1(
      Optional<NamingStrategy> namingStrategy,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcCustomConversions customConversions,
      @Qualifier("db1") RelationalManagedTypes jdbcManagedTypes) {
    return base.jdbcMappingContext(namingStrategy, customConversions, jdbcManagedTypes);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public JdbcConverter jdbcConverterDb1(
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcMappingContext mappingContext,
      @Qualifier("db1") NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations,
      @Qualifier("db1") @Lazy RelationResolver relationResolver,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcCustomConversions conversions,
      @Qualifier("db1") Dialect dialect) {
    return base.jdbcConverter(mappingContext, operations, relationResolver, conversions, dialect);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversionsDb1() {
    return base.jdbcCustomConversions();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public JdbcAggregateTemplate jdbcAggregateTemplateDb1(
      ApplicationContext applicationContext,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcMappingContext mappingContext,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcConverter converter,
      @Qualifier("db1") DataAccessStrategy dataAccessStrategy) {
    return base.jdbcAggregateTemplate(applicationContext, mappingContext, converter, dataAccessStrategy);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public DataAccessStrategy dataAccessStrategyDb1(
      @Qualifier("db1") NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcConverter jdbcConverter,
      @Qualifier("db1") JdbcMappingContext context,
      @Qualifier("db1") Dialect dialect) {
    return base.dataAccessStrategyBean(operations, jdbcConverter, context, dialect);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("db1")
  public Dialect jdbcDialectDb1(@Qualifier("db1") NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations) {
    return base.jdbcDialect(operations);
  }

  public static class JdbcRepositoryFactoryBeanDb1<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends
      JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    public JdbcRepositoryFactoryBeanDb1(Class<T> repositoryInterface) {
      super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataAccessStrategy(@Qualifier("db1") DataAccessStrategy dataAccessStrategy) {
      super.setDataAccessStrategy(dataAccessStrategy);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcOperations(@Qualifier("db1") NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations) {
      super.setJdbcOperations(operations);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setMappingContext(@Qualifier("db1") RelationalMappingContext mappingContext) {
      super.setMappingContext(mappingContext);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDialect(@Qualifier("db1") Dialect dialect) {
      super.setDialect(dialect);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setConverter(@Qualifier("db1") JdbcConverter converter) {
      super.setConverter(converter);
    }
  }
}

Updated test
package com.kota65535;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT;

import com.kota65535.controller.User;
import com.kota65535.controller.Users;
import com.kota65535.repository.one.Db1UserRepository;
import com.kota65535.repository.two.Db2UserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.bean.override.mockito.MockitoSpyBean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class UsersControllerTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  int port;
  RestTemplate client;

  @MockitoSpyBean
  Db1UserRepository repository1;

  @MockitoSpyBean
  Db2UserRepository repository2;

  @BeforeEach
  void beforeEach() {
    client = new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .rootUri("http://localhost:%d".formatted(port))
        .build();
  }

  @Test
  void testGetUsers() {
    Users users = client.getForObject("/users", Users.class);
    assertNotNull(users);
    assertThat(users.getUsers()).hasSize(4);

    // "foo", "bar" are from db1, "hoge", "piyo" from db2
    assertThat(users.getUsers())
            .extracting(User::getName)
            .containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar", "hoge", "piyo");

    verify(repository1).findAll();
    verify(repository2).findAll();
  }
}

I also bumped gradlew to 8.12 and Spring Boot to 3.4.1.
